# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.49.2:8443: i/o timeout

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, ubuntu-22.04

Hello can anyone help me I am trying to run `kubectl run my-nginx --image nginx` but it is not working moreover when I try to get all the pods in the kubernetes `kubectl get pods` . Does anyone have idea why the pods were not running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You provide very little information that would enable us to help you debug the error. You will need to prove to yourself that the cluster is running. If you're confident that the cluster is running correctly, then I suspect the error is in the `kubectl` config YAML file. On Linux, this file is conventionally to be found in `${HOME}/.kube/config`.